# Send multiple POST requests to insert x number amount of records into a database

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a application that tracks the users location on a run or doing exercise. I have a function that is called when the user clicks 'stop'.

This then executes a `POST` request to create a new record for the particular run that just took place. I then have a separate table to store all latitude/longitudes that belong to that run. Obviously depending how often I capture the users location, this could become quite a large amount of times I want to call a second `POST` request to insert the lat/long of a particular run.

```
private func saveRun()
{
    var storedResponse:NSString
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchEach = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "PHP FILE THAT CREATES A NEW RECORD FOR A RUN")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "id=\(MainMenuViewController.myVariables.user_id)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
    {
        data, response, error in



        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        MainMenuViewController.myVariables.new_run_id = responseString! as String
        dispatchGroup.leave()
        print ("Run ID =\(MainMenuViewController.myVariables.new_run_id))")
    }
    task.resume()

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    {
        for location in self.locationList
        {
            var timestamp = location.timestamp
            var latitude:String = String(format:"%f", location.coordinate.latitude)
            var longitude:String = String(format:"%f", location.coordinate.longitude)

            let requestGps = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "PHP FILE THAT CREATES RECORDS FOR EACH RECORDED LONG")! as URL)
            requestGps.httpMethod = "POST"
            let postStringGps = "id=\(MainMenuViewController.myVariables.new_run_id)&lng=\(longitude)&lat=\(latitude)&time=13:28:33"

            requestGps.httpBody = postStringGps.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let taskGps = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestGps as URLRequest)
            {
                dataGps, responseGps, errorGps in


                print(postStringGps)

                if errorGps != nil
                {
                    print("error=\(String(describing: errorGps))")
                    return
                }

                print("response = \(String(describing: responseGps))")

                let responseStringGps = NSString(data: dataGps!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                print ("responseString =\(responseStringGps!))")
            }
            taskGps.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

This code successfully creates a new record in `run_history` table. But for some reason when I execute the second POST to create new records in `run_gps`, it does not work.

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Unrelated but do not use `NSMutableURLRequest`. Just use `URLRequest`. And don't use `NSString`, use `String`.

Comment: "But for some reason when I execute the second POST to create new records in run_gps,"  What is run_gps?  A table name?

Comment: @ElTomato yes `run_gps` is a table name.

Comment: How do you go from posting a record to one table to posting a record to another table?

Comment: Some queries - What is the purpose of ```dispatchEach```? Are you sure there are items in ```self.locationList```? When you say it does not work, does the API fail or succeed but doesn't update DB?

Comment: @Varun `dispatchEach` was something I was testing and `self.locationList` does have some items due it looping x amount of times. The code that is there _should_ work. It just doesn't update the DB, it only inserts the **first** item.

Comment: @ElTomato I don't understand?